# Docker service is not started in Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm learning `Ansible` with the idea of using it locally in my laptop and currently I'm working with the "includes".

I'd like to prepare a playbook to import some other tasks (installing base packages, set up git, vim and docker) and execute it.

> All the code is hosted in `GitLab` and I'm using their free `CI` service to test the plays.

The CI job will run until when checking if the `docker` service is running. At this point, the play will fail with the following message:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": ["service", "docker", "restart"], 
    "delta": "0:00:00.176233",
    "end": "2017-09-28 18:49:56.194752",
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2017-09-28 18:49:56.018519",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

I've created a docker container (`docker run --rm -ti debian`) in my laptop and executed the play locally and it fails in the same spot.

**However**, if the container is created with the `privileged` flag, I can start the service by hand and then re-execute the play. This time, it will finish successfully.

---

So, my questions are:

- How can I start the `docker` service using `Ansible`?

  - Am I doing it completely wrong and there is a better way to get this working?
- When running the container in my laptop, I created it in `privilege` mode. This allowed me to start the service *by-hand*.

  - Since I can't modify the way the containers are created in the `GitLab-CI`public instance:
  - Could be a possible solution to add my own runner to the project with the `privileged` flag enabled?

**PS:** At the moment, I'm not exactly looking into best practices, I'm just trying to get this running to have something to play with.

**Environment:**

- Ansible: 2.4.0
- Python: 2.7.13
- Docker: 17.09.0-ce

## --- --- ---

The `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: debian:latest

variables:
  HOST_INVENTORY: "./hosts"
  INCLUDES_DIR: "./gists/includes"

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -y curl gcc g++ openssh-server openssh-client python python-dev python-setuptools libffi-dev libssl-dev
  - easy_install pip
  - pip install ansible

stages:
  - syntax_check
  - install

check:
  stage: syntax_check
  script:      
    - ansible-playbook -i $HOST_INVENTORY $INCLUDES_DIR/play.yml --limit 'local' --syntax-check;

run_includes:
    stage: install
    script:
        - ANSIBLE_PIPELINING=True ansible-playbook -i $HOST_INVENTORY $INCLUDES_DIR/play.yml --limit 'local';
```

---

The `play.yml` is quite simple, only importing some plays:

```
- hosts: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  pre_tasks:
    - import_tasks: tasks/pre.yml # update package manager cache

  tasks:
    - import_tasks: tasks/common.yml
    - import_tasks: tasks/docker.yml
```

---

And the `docker` tasks:

```
- name: Dependencies
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: installed
  with_items:
    - apt-transport-https
    - ca-certificates
    - curl
    - gnupg2
    - software-properties-common

- name: Docker module dependencies
  pip:
      name: docker-py

- name: Add Docker key
  shell: curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg | apt-key add -

- name: Add Docker repo
  shell: echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo $ID) $(lsb_release -cs) stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

- name: Install Docker
  apt:
    pkg: docker-ce
    state: installed
    update_cache: yes

- name: Ensure Docker group is present
  group:
    name: docker
    state: present

- name: Add current user to the Docker group
  user:
    name: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    groups:
      - docker
    append: yes

- name: Ensure service is enabled
  command: service docker restart

- name: Pull images from Docker hub
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - debian
    - cern/cc7-base
```

Comment: None of your steps actually starts docker service!

Comment: @Deano In my Debian, executing `service docker restart` with a stopped service will start it. Could it be a different behaviour in Ansible?

Comment: I haven't used ansible to install docker, but I have used it to manage it, you shouldn't see different behavior, to ensure service is started, maybe use `service name=docker state=started`

Comment: I had it like that at the beginning, but it wasn't working, so I tried directly with the command.

Comment: is this trying to run docker within a docker container?

Comment: What Gitlab runner/executor have your configured?

Comment: @TarunLalwani  The runner is one of the shared ones provided by `gitlab.com` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I created a sample project on `gitlab.com` which runs few command on the runner

```
$ echo PWD is $PWD
PWD is /builds/tarunlalwani/testci
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.1  20260  2984 ?        Ss   19:41   0:00 /bin/bash
root         7  0.0  0.1  20420  2652 ?        S    19:41   0:00 /bin/bash
root        10  0.0  0.0  17500  1996 ?        R    19:41   0:00 ps aux
$ which systemctl
/bin/systemctl
$ systemctl status docker
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As you can see we are running inside a container and hence your ansible script is not going to work. There is no docker service to start or end. Also since you are inside a docker container, restarting docker container also means killing the container you are running.

You need to setup a Ubuntu VM and then setup Gitlab Runner with a Shell executor on the same. The shell executor will mean that your commands run on that VM, which will have `systemctl` and `docker` service

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help! I'll set up a runner for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [GitLab's `dind` service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor) that will let us test the playbooks inside a container using the shared runners that are already provided.

Two things are needed here:

1. A `Dockerfile` where to build a base image with all the requirements to run Ansible.
2. A modified `gitlab-ci` file to run the jobs inside a container.

As an example, the `Dockerfile` could look like this:

```
FROM debian:latest
ARG USERNAME

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl \
                       git \
                       gcc \
                       g++ \
                       libffi-dev \
                       libssl-dev \
                       openssh-client \
                       openssh-server \
                       python \
                       python-dev \
                       python-setuptools \
                       sudo

RUN easy_install pip && \
    pip install ansible \
                jmespath

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash $USERNAME
USER $USERNAME
WORKDIR /home/$USERNAME
```

And then, in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file, we can have something like:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_IMAGE: "registry.gitlab.com/<YOUR_USER>/<YOUR_REPO>/dummy-image"
  CONTAINER_NAME: "test"
  IMAGE_USERNAME: "dummy"

stages:
  - build
  - check

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
after_script:
  - docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
  - docker rmi $DOCKER_IMAGE
  - docker logout registry.gitlab.com

build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $DOCKER_IMAGE --build-arg USERNAME=$IMAGE_USERNAME .
    - docker push $DOCKER_IMAGE
  when: manual

check_version:
  stage: check
  script:
      - docker run -di --name $CONTAINER_NAME $DOCKER_IMAGE
      - docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash -c "ansible-playbook --version"
```

This has also the added benefit that all the pre-requisites for Ansible to run are set in the `build` stage and they don't need to be repeated again every time the CI process is run (like with the original `gitlab-ci.yml` file in the question).